# Validate with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have such js script, which validates my form:

```
    $.validator.addMethod("uploadFile", function(value, element){
        var size = element.files.size;
        alert(size);
        if(size <= 52428800)
            return true;
    });

    $(selector).validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $(form).ajaxSubmit(options);
        },
        focusInvalid: true,
        focusCleanup: true,
        rules: {   
            file: {
                required: false,
                uploadFile: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            uploadFile: {
                required: "Maximum upload size 50MB. Please try again"
            }

        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            var er = element.attr("name");
            element.addClass('error');
        }
    });
```

How I can print message "Maximum upload size 50MB. Please try again" in a span? I read in internet, but I can't find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the content of DOM-elements with jQuery.

```
$('#YourSpanId').html("Maximum upload size 50MB. Please try again");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.validator.addMethod("uploadFile", function(value, element){
    var size = element.files.size;
    alert(size);
    if(size <= 52428800)
        return true;
});


$(selector).validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $(form).ajaxSubmit(options);
    },
    focusInvalid: true,
    focusCleanup: true,
    rules: {   
        file: {
            required: false,
            uploadFile: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        uploadFile: {
            required: "Maximum upload size 50MB. Please try again"
            minlength:"Maximum upload size 50MB. Please try again"
        }

    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        var er = element.attr("name");
        element.addClass('error');
    }
});
```